# C#. Использование ролей авторизации для разрешения вызова метода

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Здравствуйте!

В старом приложении на C# (WinForms) вручную (без использования внешних фреймворков авторизации/аутентификации) написана примитивная система входа пользователей в систему под ролями.
Нужно добавить в код разграничение доступа по ролям.
Т.е. вызов методов или событий возможен для определенных ролей.

Было бы идеально указывать права доступа через атрибут на метода (как в ASP.Net MVC)

```
[Role("Admin")]
public void Foo()
{

}
```

Все примеры использования атрибутов, которые я видел, это вытягивание параметров атрибута в самом методе через рефлексию. Но тогда мне проще создать сервис проверки, который вызывать в начале каждого метода, сервис внедрять через DI.

Можно ли, как то в коде атрибута Role, прописать что он вызывается до метода, на который он применен, и проверить роль текущего пользователя, и выдать или запретить команду на исполнение самого метода?

Comment: Или создать сервис проверки или использовать AOP-фреймворк. Самым известным является PostSharp, но платный. Можно поискать бесплатные альтернативы.

Answer (score 2):

Возможен следующий подход "руками".

После успешной авторизации, например, следующим образом задается принципал безопасности:

```
GenericIdentity myIdentity = new GenericIdentity(_username);
GenericPrincipal myPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(myIdentity, new string[] { "Administrator" });

AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
currentDomain.SetThreadPrincipal(myPrincipal);
```

Далее проверять роль можно явно в коде

```
if (Thread.CurrentPrincipal.IsInRole("Administrator")))
```

Или через атрибут (использовать не приходилось, не могу гарантировать, что будет работать)

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "Administrator")]
```

Comment: В ASP.NET такие атрибуты учитываются самим "движком" asp.net. В WinForms такой "движок" (или "сервис", как его назвал автор вопроса) отсутствует, его нужно реализовать самому.